# Android bitmap crop 5 or more corners

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, crop, rectangles

I'm working crop operations on bitmaps. 
Giving starting point, height, width,  easy clipping.Like this

```
lastImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(firstImage,x,y,width, height);
```

In this way, an area can be cut rectangle. But i dont want this for somae cases. It can be 5 or more sides(ex:pentagon). It sometimes goes out to the edge crop areas. I'm trying to tell this;
[image]

How i can crop image with this area. I am using OpenCV for image processing. Can I use it for this process.

Comment: You can use [copyTo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#mat-copyto) with a mask

Comment: @Miki thank you advice, i can crop like this but I just want my crop field. Two images(input and cropped image) same width and height.Without background, how do I ensure that only cropped area.

Comment: I don't get what you mean